# BaseObject which can have NSObject,Mappable and Object swift

Tags: swift, realm, alamofire, objectmapper

i Have a BaseRequestObject of type NSObject,Mappable which is inherit by a object called User. I need to save this User object inside realmDB.

```
class BaseRequestBody: NSObject,Mappable {
override init() {

}

required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {

}
```

}

UserObject which inhertits BaseRequestBody:-

```
class User: BaseRequestBody {
var id : String?
var name : String?    

override init() {
    super.init()
}

required init?(map: Map) {
    super.init(map: map)
}

override func mapping(map: Map) {
id     <- map["id"]
name   <- map["name"]
}
}
```

How to use this User object to store both in realmDatabase and use as a normal object.I am using this same object to parse alamofire data to userObject.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to make `BaseRequestBody` inherit from `NSObject`, `Object` inherits from `RLMObjectBase`, which inherits from `NSObject`, so simply making `BaseRequestBody` a subclass of `Object` will also make it a subclass of `NSObject`.

```
class BaseRequestBody: Object,Mappable {
...
}
```

Unrelated to your issue, but there's no need to use `ObjectMapper` for decoding your object from JSON, you can simply use the `Decodable` protocol.